# How to reset subset row positions to row position 0 in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'Number':np.arange(9)})
```

Which yields:

```
    Number
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
```

I then want to subset it into 3 different chunks with the code:

```
V1 = DF.query('Number > -1 and Number < 3')
V2 = DF.query('Number > 2 and Number < 6')
V3 = DF.query('Number > 5 and Number < 9')
```

Giving 3 new tables of:

V1

```
    Number
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

V2

```
    Number
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

V3

```
    Number
6   6
7   7
8   8
```

How do I write the code as to reset the rows for each data frame back to position 0 so that:

V1

```
    Number
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

V2

```
    Number
0   3
1   4
2   5
```

V3 =

```
    Number
0   6
1   7
2   8
```

Thank you.

Comment: call `reset_index(drop=True)` on each slice

Comment: Excellent, that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, slicing the original dataframe into 3 new dataframes:

```
V1 = DF[(DF.Number > -1) & (DF.Number < 3)]
V2 = DF[(DF.Number > 2) & (DF.Number < 6)]
V3 = DF[(DF.Number > 5) & (DF.Number < 9)]
```

Then reset the index of the dataframes that you need:

```
V2 = V2.reset_index(drop=True)
V3 = V3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### * OP Edit *

Placing the reset code in line:

```py
V1 = DF[(DF.Number > -1) & (DF.Number < 3)]
V2 = DF[(DF.Number > 2) & (DF.Number < 6)].reset_index(drop = True)
V3 = DF[(DF.Number > 5) & (DF.Number < 9)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Yup! Thank you for this. Should have known it was easy.

Comment: Updated to accept this answer, `pd.DataFrame.query` is not the common strategy (and seems to be less efficient through testing). The above technique is regarded as the current best practice. I'll add an edit also to decrease the line count but just placing `reset_index` in line with the split.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum), "call `reset_index(drop=True)` on each slice".

So:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'Number':np.arange(9)})

V1 = DF.query('Number > -1 and Number < 3')
V2 = DF.query('Number > 2 and Number < 6')
V3 = DF.query('Number > 5 and Number < 9')

V1.reset_index(drop=True)
V2.reset_index(drop=True)
V3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Yields:

```
    Number
0   0
1   1
2   2

    Number
0   3
1   4
2   5

    Number
0   6
1   7
2   8
```